# Android : Gcm is calling 3 times

Tags: android, json, google-cloud-messaging

When I send the data from the server to the device, gcm block is executing 3 times and the JSON format is changing as not usual.

This is the Gcm code.

```
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
    if (!extras.isEmpty()) { // has effect of unparcelling Bundle
        /*
         * Filter messages based on message type. Since it is likely that
         * GCM will be extended in the future with new message types, just
         * ignore any message types you're not interested in, or that you
         * don't recognize.
         */
        if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR
                .equals(messageType)) {
            sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
        } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED
                .equals(messageType)) {
            sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: "
                    + extras.toString());
            // If it's a regular GCM message, do some work.
        } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE
                .equals(messageType)) {
            try {
                Log.i("gcmmessage",extras.toString());
                }
               catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            sendNotification("New contact received");
        }
      }
      GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
      }
```

If the type of the message is gcm means then am receiving all the data.

This portion is calling for 3 times.

```
else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE
            .equals(messageType)) {
        try {
            Log.i("gcmmessage",extras.toString());
            }
           catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

     }
```

I think this JSON format is correct.

```
 "contacts":[  
     {  
        "first_name":"kabilan",
        "last_name":"Ram",
     }
    ]
```

But Instead of receiving like before one am receiving like following format

```
contacts=[  
     {  
        "first_name":"kabilan",
        "last_name":"Ram",
     }
    ]
```

But When I have checked in server side , It is sending the data in a correct format. When I receive the data , I'am facing this problem.

Please could someone help me to solve my problem.

Comment: Can you paste your server code for sending messages? It could be that you are calling `sendPacket()` thrice.